# How does drupal set user cookie

Tags: users, sessions, cookies

The following code, let's login any user programmatically.

```
global $user;
$user = user_load(<any_uid>);
```

My question is how does the above code triggers to set new user cookies on browser, at this point we are not even regenerating session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The following code, let's login any user programmatically.

Not exactly; it sets the current global user object to an instance of a user, but it doesn't log the account in or touch the session. Many things that happen in that request that rely on the global user object will behave the same as if the account *was* logged in, but it won't be, and they won't have a session tied to the account (not yet anyway).

Cookies are added at the end of the request, in [`drupal_session_commit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21session.inc/function/drupal_session_commit/7.x):

```
if (!drupal_session_started()) {
  drupal_session_start();
  if ($is_https && variable_get('https', FALSE)) {
    $insecure_session_name = substr(session_name(), 1);
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    $expire = $params['lifetime'] ? REQUEST_TIME + $params['lifetime'] : 0;
    setcookie($insecure_session_name, $_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name], $expire, $params['path'], $params['domain'], FALSE, $params['httponly']);
  }
}
```

As a by-product of the way Drupal initialises sessions (lazily in an exit hook), if the call to `$user = user_load(<any_uid>);` happens before the first session has been initialised, the session will be initialised for that user and they will appear "logged in" for their next request, even if the `user_load` line doesn't execute.

But, `hook_user_login` won't have been invoked, the last login column in the user table won't be updated, and so on. It's not a full-on "login", just initialising the session for a particular user.

Incidentally, if you call `$user = user_load(<any_uid>);` when a session already exists for another user, the session for the next request will still be for that other user. It won't be overridden with a session for `<any_uid>`.

Comment: thanks a lot @clive, wrapping my head to digest, thanks again!

Comment: No worries, it was interesting to work this out; feel free to ask follow-up questions, it's still fresh :)

Comment: ah! I see my next question was what if I do drupal_goto() right after $user = $user_load(<any_uid>);, but realised drupal_goto() calls drupal_exit();

Comment: It completely makes sense now, I was missing the magic of drupal_exit(), thanks @Clive :)

Comment: Hi @clive, confused again! I see drupal_goto() invokes drupal_exit but as a fallback, in my case the redirection works so there is no chance of drupal_exit() getting called, instead the user is able to login.

Comment: If I do a die() right after the $user= user_load(<any_uid>); I see the session id gets replaced in database

Comment: I think the reason why session id get replaced in database when you do `die()` right after `user_load(<any_uid>) `is because of drupal uses `_drupal_session_write()` function as session write handler in `session_set_save_handler()` function. This `_drupal_session_write()` function get executed right before script exits and in this function drupal update the existing session with new user id. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php for more detail.

Comment: The session gets written and closed in a registered shutdown function, which runs even when `die` is used . Many layers at work here